# Pyspark session error: "requirement failed: key cannot be null"

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I try to start a Spark Session on Jupyter Notebook (Spark 3.2., Hadoop 3.2., Jupyter NB 6.1.4., Python 3.8.5).

I set up the environment:

```
%env
SPARK_HOME = "C:/Spark/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2"
PATH = "C:/Spark/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/bin"
PYSPARK_PYTHON = "C:/Users/xxx/anaconda3/python.exe"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = "C:/Users/xxx/anaconda3/Scripts/jupyter.exe"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS = "notebook"
```

And then try to start my session

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, BooleanType
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").config().getOrCreate()
```

But I have this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4872c558dab5> in <module>
      5 from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
      6 from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, BooleanType
----> 7 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").config("spark.some.config.option","some-value").getOrCreate() 

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    231                     session = SparkSession(sc)
    232                 for key, value in self._options.items():
--> 233                     session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
    234                 return session
    235 

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1307 
   1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
   1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1311 

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    116                 # JVM exception message.
--> 117                 raise converted from None
    118             else:
    119                 raise

IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: key cannot be null
```

Any idea?